# Point-in-Time Snapshot of Profile

Tags: feature-request, stack-overflow, network-profile

Can there be a feature in StackOverflow to "rewind" and see your Point-In-Time profile view?

The purpose, arguably, would be to see how your profile appeared a year ago.  It is an extension of the historic scoring.

I'd like to see what my profile looked like last year on this day.

Can I do it???

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Can there be a feature in StackOverflow to "rewind" and see your Point-In-Time profile view?

You can recover at least some of that information yourself using the [data explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/). For example, you can use a query like [*Reputation as of date*](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/102469/reputation-as-of-date) to determine your reputation score on a given date. I'm not sure if *all* the information in your profile can be recovered this way -- for example, changes to your user name or the About Me section may not be recorded in the database, but in that case those probably couldn't be reproduced by the feature you suggest either.